# How to have a Radio Group of Button Type with gap between each button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-community, lightning-radiogroup

I would like to use a Radio Group of Button Type:

```
<lightning:radioGroup name="radioButtonGroup"
                          label="Radio Button Group"
                          options="{! v.options }"
                          value="{! v.value }"
                          type="button"/>
```

But I would like each button to display separately like they are independent.

I've tried this CSS:

```
.THIS .slds-radio_button-group {
    border: none;
}

.THIS .slds-radio_button {
    border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

But the corners are not curved

Comment: in that case, why not use lighting:input components of type checkbox? you will have more control over the css and how to distribute them in your layout

Comment: @glls I still want only one to be selectable.

Comment: you can use individual input components and have only one selected at a time

Comment: @glls sure, but then I need to write code to manage that. I would like a css solution :)

Comment: css solutions are not always the cleanest, specially when it comes to modifying namespaced components. Additionally, is there any reason why you are not using lighting web components?

Comment: @glls this project has had 18 months of development, with over 200 aura components. I am not going to switch. Other new projects will get LWC.

Comment: Oh god, that is indeed a good reason not to immediately switch over =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the actual dom rendered by the component does not match your selector:

[image]

```
.THIS div.slds-radio_button-group{
    border: none;
}

.THIS label.slds-radio_button__label {
    border-radius: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

would actually target each of your radio-buttons, additionally, you should avoid using `!important`

as this could potentially affect any other component that shared the selector. Instead, expand your selector to further specify the element you want to affect with your styling.

Directly modifying the css of namespaced components like this is not really recommended, and you should instead render your own `lighnting:input` eventhough it might mean further adding code to your javascript controller (which is not overly complicated).

[modifying a lightning component css](https://tenor.com/view/family-guy-css-open-window-annoyed-pissed-gif-12014506)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I can see you've inspected the normal radio element, whereas it's different markup for the button type

Comment: no - I used a radioGroup component, this component actually renders what you see in the screenshot. I used the code sample provided in the components library https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example

Comment: Also, the reason I don't want to build it custom with independent buttons, is because this is part of a long application process with many questions, so I will have to manage the state of lots (almost hundreds) of buttons.

Comment: Sure, but I am using the `type="button"` configuration

Comment: well - in the end it still comes down to you not using the right selectors, ive updated the answer with the appropriate screenshot, radioGroup type and selector. this should at least get you started

Comment: I am using your exact code and it's still not working :(

Comment: what context is your componet in ? lex, lighting communities?

Comment: lighting communities

Comment: you might have to play around with the selectors and/or cehck that other components are not overriding yours (some other !important 's that you might have in the community) - I used my component in a lighting community and it works.

Comment: [Fixing your CSS in lighting communities](https://tenor.com/view/family-guy-css-open-window-annoyed-pissed-gif-12014506)

Comment: Any idea who to change the colour of the button once it's selected? :)

Comment: ish, that one doenst look easily achievable, there is stlysheet that actually has the rules for that, and the selctor is a pain to find =/

Comment: I guess it's this rule `.slds-radio_button [type="radio"]:checked + .slds-radio_faux, 
.slds-radio_button [type="radio"]:checked ~ .slds-radio_faux, 
.slds-radio_button [type="radio"]:checked + .slds-radio_button__label` button it won't let me save this into my `.css` file

Comment: If anyone is ever interested, I change the selected colour of a radio button using `.THIS .slds-radio_button [type="radio"]:checked + .slds-radio_button__label {
    background-color:rgba(63, 14, 90, 0.7);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}`